# Angular Materials datepicker md-open-on-focus function just not working

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

i have the following HTML element and the calendar its supposed to open when you focus on it but it just doesn't happen, any suggestions?

```
<md-datepicker name="firstDate" ng-model="AddQuote.current.hotel.firstDate" ng-required="true" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
```

Comment: Is that relevant to your problem? https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9170

Comment: @AlonEitan thx aji but im not on mobile device, it's happening on regular browser.

Comment: Are you working with the latest version of angular material? Because there are other related issues about it (https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4650) and it works in the demos on the website

Comment: @AlonEitan well I didn't, now seems to be working but all the layouts and selects were modified, anyway I'm gonna take a look and fix it, thank you very much!